# Can't figure out how to search XML column in my table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a table called v_EpisodeAudit, with a column called EventData that contains XML data.  The XML data differs from row to row, so one record could have XML data in this column that looks like this:

```
<AddMDMDocument>
  <EpisodeMDMId>282521</EpisodeMDMId>
  <OncologyReferral>0</OncologyReferral>
  <SpecialPalliativeReferral>0</SpecialPalliativeReferral>
  <SurgeonReferral>0</SurgeonReferral>
  <MDMReport>0</MDMReport>
  <GPReferral>0</GPReferral>
  <GPReferralApproval>0</GPReferralApproval>
  <GeneralPalliativeCare>0</GeneralPalliativeCare>
  <AuditLogin>mkell010</AuditLogin>
  <AuditTrust>4</AuditTrust>
  <Error />
</AddMDMDocument>
```

while another row might contain the following XML data:

```
<CloseEpisode>
  <EpisodeId>652503</EpisodeId>
  <TrackingStatusId>9</TrackingStatusId>
  <TrackingClosureReason>100</TrackingClosureReason>
  <DateOfTrackingClosure>Sep 25 2017 12:37PM</DateOfTrackingClosure>
  <AuditLogin>ccass001</AuditLogin>
  <AuditTrust>1</AuditTrust>
  <Error />
</CloseEpisode>
```

And there are further differing types/configurations of XML data.  I've read about 20 different sources this morning trying to work out how to search against the XML data in this column to get a specific EpisodeId in the CloseEpisode XMLs, and I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Can anyone help me with a query that will find a specified EpisodeId in this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the xml querying functions

```
select EventData.value('(/CloseEpisode/EpisodeId)[1]','int')
from v_EpisodeAudit
where EventData.value('local-name(/*[1])','varchar(100)')='CloseEpisode'
```

or perhaps

```
select EventData 
from @v_EpisodeAudit
where EventData.value('(/CloseEpisode/EpisodeId)[1]','int')=652503
```

depending on what you're trying to do.

If you don't know the root node name, you could use

```
 select EventData.value('(//EpisodeId)[1]','int')
 from v_EpisodeAudit
 where EventData.exist('//EpisodeId')=1
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type

Comment: That's great, worked like a charm.  Thanks.  Follow-up question.  What if I wanted to find EpisodeId without knowing the XML parent, eg. without knowing it was within CloseEpisode - how would I find EpisodeId regardless of where it was?

Comment: @ailinmcc666 Doesn't my answer completely cover this issue (unknown element name)?

Comment: I apologize, it does indeed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

XML can be queried very generically. Some approaches:

```
DECLARE @v_EpisodeAudit TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, [EventData] XML);
INSERT INTO @v_EpisodeAudit VALUES
 (N'<AddMDMDocument>
  <EpisodeMDMId>282521</EpisodeMDMId>
  <OncologyReferral>0</OncologyReferral>
  <SpecialPalliativeReferral>0</SpecialPalliativeReferral>
  <SurgeonReferral>0</SurgeonReferral>
  <MDMReport>0</MDMReport>
  <GPReferral>0</GPReferral>
  <GPReferralApproval>0</GPReferralApproval>
  <GeneralPalliativeCare>0</GeneralPalliativeCare>
  <AuditLogin>mkell010</AuditLogin>
  <AuditTrust>4</AuditTrust>
  <Error />
</AddMDMDocument>')
,(N'<CloseEpisode>
  <EpisodeId>652503</EpisodeId>
  <TrackingStatusId>9</TrackingStatusId>
  <TrackingClosureReason>100</TrackingClosureReason>
  <DateOfTrackingClosure>Sep 25 2017 12:37PM</DateOfTrackingClosure>
  <AuditLogin>ccass001</AuditLogin>
  <AuditTrust>1</AuditTrust>
  <Error />
</CloseEpisode>');00
```

--This will return the very first node on the second level

```
SELECT ID
      ,vEA.[EventData].value(N'local-name(/*[1]/*[1])',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,vEA.[EventData].value(N'/*[1]/*[1]/text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @v_EpisodeAudit AS vEA
```

--This will return all nodes of the sevond level and use `WHERE` with `LIKE` to find the Episode..Id elements

```
SELECT ID
      ,SecondLevelNode.Nd.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,SecondLevelNode.Nd.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @v_EpisodeAudit AS vEA
OUTER APPLY vEA.[EventData].nodes(N'/*/*') AS SecondLevelNode(Nd)
WHERE SecondLevelNode.Nd.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') LIKE 'Episode%' --or LIKE 'Episode%Id'
```

--Similar but filtering on XQuery level

```
SELECT ID
      ,SecondLevelNode.Nd.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,SecondLevelNode.Nd.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @v_EpisodeAudit AS vEA
OUTER APPLY vEA.[EventData].nodes(N'/*/*[substring(local-name(),1,7)="Episode"]') AS SecondLevelNode(Nd)
```